# Public key error connecting to AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance on Mac with .pub file, username and host name

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am a newbie to AWS and need some help. I have a .pub file, a host name and username. I have been trying to connect to the server, but keep getting a Permission denied (publickey) error. Someone else set up the instance.

The .pub file is on my desktop. I am in desktop in my directory. Did chmod 400 to the .pub file. I then try: 
ssh -i /Users/machine/Desktop/filename.pub ubuntu@placeholder.com

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need the private key to connect to EC2.

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```